# Working with ajax to change some items in mongoDB without refreshing the site

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I have 'orders page' where orders should appear and could be changed with ajax without reloading the page. How do i make it to change specific boolean in mongoDB on a button click? Also i need to refresh page every time a new order comes up without reloading the page.

It works great with reloading the page with routing, but i need AJAX.

Script.js

```
  $('.confirm').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'order/' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '/confirm',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(){
      }
  });
});
```

index.ejs

```
<form class="confirm" data-id="<%= order.id %>" method="POST">
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Priimti</button>
</form>
```

orders.js

```
router.post('/order/:id/confirm', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
      Order.findOneAndUpdate({_id: (req.params.id)}, { $set: { isConfirmed: true, isDone: false } }, { returnOriginal: false }, (err, result) => {
        if (err){
          console.log(err);
        }
    });
  });
```

So the site should be updating orders parameters such as 'isConfirmed' from false to true in mongoDB on a click of a button without reloading. Also ALL orders should appear on the site without reloading as well.

Comment: I know it must have some code in 'success' , but what do I need to write there to update the order?

Comment: What doesn't work about your code?  Are you getting errors, is the data not being saved, etc.

Comment: So basically there are a few sections on the page. “Waiting for confirmation orders” “pending orders” “done orders” and when the button is clicked it supposed to replace the order to a new section, but that doesn’t happen until I reload the page

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `success: function(someVar)` part of your ajax call.  This tells your code what it should do after the call is made, and any context you pass from your route will be accessible through `someVar`.  For example:

assuming your index.html looks like this, and that you are using jQuery:

```
  $.ajax({
  url: 'order/' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '/confirm',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(data){
      //code to change the html of "someDiv"
      $('#someDiv').html(data['someData']);
  }
```

On a side note, I would recommend *always* passing `e` in your functions, instead of calling `event.preventDefault()` because `event` by itself doesn't work on Firefox sometimes.  For example:

```
$('.confirm').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
...
```

Lastly, I don't think you need the `event.stopPropagation`.

Comment: But all I have to change in the success function is order value from “isConfirmed = false” to “isConfirmed = true”. I don’t need to change anything in the html itself, because it renders with .ejs based on orders value